# Hi , this PHP code send me all the checkboxes and not the checked by the user

Tags: php, html

```
    $checkboxValues = [];
    
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // Verifica si el campo es un checkbox y si está marcado
        if (strpos($key, 'baños_opcion') === 0 && isset($_POST[$key])) {
            $checkboxValues[] = $_POST[$key];
        }
    }
}

$toilette = implode(", ", $checkboxValues);

$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_form_submissions (nombre, apellido, email, observaciones, resultado, toilette)
        VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$email', '$observaciones', '$resultado', '$toilette')";
```

my html

```
  <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion6" value="ninguno: 0m"/>
  <input type="checkbox"  name="baños_opcion6[]" value="0" />
  
  <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion7" value="toilette: 2.10m"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion7"  value="2.10" />
  
  <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion8" value="simple: 4.32m"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion8" value="2.10" />
        
  <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion9" value="Antebaño: 8.46m"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion9" value="8.46" />
```

The array i recieve is :
Datos insertados correctamente en la base de datos.Valores de los campos de checkbox:

```
ninguno: 0m, 
toilette: 2.10m, 
simple: 4.32m, 
Antebaño: 8.46m
```

and i only expect the checked option of the user

Comment: If you only want the checked options, get rid of the hidden fields

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but if i get rid of the hidden options i dont receive any value at all

Comment: First Problem: Your hidden fields have the same `name` attribute as the associated checkboxes? APart from this one `name="baños_opcion6[]"` which appears to be an anomoly Thsi is causing you confusion as to what is being sent from the form

Comment: INFO: Unchecked checkboxes are not sent from the form to the backend

Comment: `if i get rid of the hidden options i dont receive any value at all `...you'll get only the checked values, which is what you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't be mixing in the hidden inputs like this, unless you really need them as they will cause issues like what you have encountered.

The values you are getting in the loop are the hidden input values rather than the checkbox ones.
Since you have the same input name, values will clash.

However, based on the understanding that you need the hidden input's value corresponding to the checkbox selected, you can try modifying the code as below.

In the HTML separate the name attribute of the hidden inputs and checkboxes.

```
  <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion7" value="toilette: 2.10m"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion_check_7"  value="2.10" />
  
  <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion8" value="simple: 4.32m"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion_check_8" value="2.10" />
        
  <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion9" value="Antebaño: 8.46m"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion_check_9" value="8.46" />
```

For the PHP you can change as below

```
$checkboxValues = [];

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // Verifica si el campo es un checkbox y si está marcado
    if (strpos($key, 'baños_opcion_check_') === 0 && isset($_POST[$key])) {
        $input_key = str_replace("_check_","",$key);
        $checkboxValues[] = $_POST[$input_key];
    }
    }
}

$toilette = implode(", ", $checkboxValues);

$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_form_submissions (nombre, apellido, email, observaciones, resultado, toilette)
        VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$email', '$observaciones', '$resultado', '$toilette')";
```

In the PHP portion, the if condition was changed to identify the checkbox name only. As a second step the `$input_key` removes the `_check_` to arrive at the name for the hidden input for the checkbox.

Full PHP file for the working test

```
<?php
$checkboxValues = [];
if (!empty($_POST)){
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // Verifica si el campo es un checkbox y si está marcado
    if (strpos($key, 'baños_opcion_check_') === 0 && isset($_POST[$key])) {
        $input_key = str_replace("_check_","",$key);
        $checkboxValues[] = $_POST[$input_key];
    }
    }

    var_dump($checkboxValues);
    exit();
}

?>


<form method="POST">
      <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion6" value="ninguno: 0m"/>
      <input type="checkbox"  name="baños_opcion_check_6[]" value="0" />
      
      <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion7" value="toilette: 2.10m"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion_check_7"  value="2.10" />
      
      <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion8" value="simple: 4.32m"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion_check_8" value="2.10" />
            
      <input type ="hidden" name="baños_opcion9" value="Antebaño: 8.46m"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion_check_9" value="8.46" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey @Fran, I tested the code before posting the solution, I am able to see an array print the value of any checkbox I check before pressing submit.

I have updated the answer to include my full test file, which is working at my end, perhaps you can give it another try?

Comment: I made a localhost php file e and run it and it work ofcourse :) i may have a script or something on wordpress that interfere , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that you are using the same `name` attribute for both hidden inputs and check boxes. To get only the checked check boxes, you should give unique `name` attributes to each checkbox.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="baños_opcion6_desc" value="ninguno: 0m" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion6" value="0" />

    <input type="hidden" name="baños_opcion7_desc" value="toilette: 2.10m" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion7" value="2.10" />

    <input type="hidden" name="baños_opcion8_desc" value="simple: 4.32m" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion8" value="4.32" />

    <input type="hidden" name="baños_opcion9_desc" value="Antebaño: 8.46m" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="baños_opcion9" value="8.46" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

PHP:

```
$checkboxValues = [];

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // Check if the field is a checkbox and if it's checked
    if (isset($_POST[$key . '_desc'])) {
        $checkboxValues[] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}

$toilette = implode(", ", $checkboxValues);

print_r($toilette);
```

This should work as expected!